# Sequelize: How to make relationship between 3 tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

If you have the following entities: Users, Roles, Organizations.
You want to setup the relationships so that each user has an organization-role.

In simple each user can belong to multiple organizations and the user has a specific role in each organization.

**How would you model this with Sequelize?**

*I have tried by creating a junction table called organisation_users and then in that table adding a organisationUsers.belongsTo(role);
From I have read Sequelize doesnt support associations on junction tables and so that solution doesn't work.*

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequelize does supports associations on join table. You should look in the "through" options [here >](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

Example :

```
const Asso_Organization_User = sequelize.define('Asso_Organization_User', {
    id: DataTypes.STRING,
    userId: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: DataTypes.STRING
});
User.Organizations = User.belongsToMany(Organization, {
    through: Asso_Organization_User,
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    otherKey: 'organizationId',
    as: 'organizations'
})
```

But your case is a bit special, I dont see a way using sequelize to get a user, all of its organizations, and his role for each organization in the same query.
It looks like there is no solution yet, based on this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6671

Maybe you could do it in two queries : get all organizations and all roles, and then merging them with code.

**Actually, I see another solution:**

```
const Asso_Organization_User = sequelize.define('Asso_Organization_User', {
    id: DataTypes.STRING,
    userId: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: DataTypes.STRING
});
User.Organizations = User.belongsToMany(Organization, {
    through: Asso_Organization_User,
    foreignKey: 'userId',
    otherKey: 'organizationId',
    as: 'organizations'
})
```

The model would look like the following :

```
User: id
Role: id, userId, organizationId
Organizations: id
Asso_Organization_User: id, userId, organizationId
```

Then :

```
User.Organizations = User.belongsToMany(Organization, {
    through: Asso_Organization_User
})
Organization.Roles = Organization.haMany(Role, {
    foreignKey: 'organizationId'
})
```

And then you should be able to query :

```
   User.findAll({
        include: [ {
            model: Organization,
            include: {
                model: Role  
            }
        } ]
        where: {
            'role.userId': Sequelize.col("User.id")
        }
    });
```

I'm not totally sure of the exact syntax, but combining Sequelize.col with the hasMany should work. But be careful, if you dont add this where clause, this would return all roles for each organization (for every user having a role in this organization).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this out Philippe, I will test it out in the next 2 days and get back to you.

Comment: Adding a complication to the problem :p... I have the concept of permissions and roles, a role is just a combination of permissions. So Roles has a belongs to many with permissions. With this in regards what would you do with the 
`Role: id, userId, organizationId` model?

Comment: It would not change the Role model, your Permission table would just have a roleId column pointing to the role.

Comment: I am quite new to sequelize, so apologies for some of the questions. If permissions and roles has a many to many relationship how would I establish:
"your Permission table would just have a roleId column pointing to the role".
Currently I have a role_permissions table, which has permission and role ID foreign keys.

Comment: In case of a many to many you indeed need a role_permission table making the association between the two. For that I suggest looking at sequelize doc, especially the part "many-to-many" associations, looking for the "through" option : http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations Feel free to ask a new question if you need further help in this area.

Comment: Thank you. I did create a join table called by simply adding a sequelize model relation (belongsToMany) on the permissions and the roles models. That works fine. The part I am unsure about is now making the link between 
`User: id
Organizations: id
Asso_Organization_User: id, userId, organizationId`

and

`role / role_permissions`

Comment: The same way as we did for including the other associations, you should use "include" on the role when making your query

Comment: Thank you, let me give it a shot and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: hahaha, dont worry i wont hesitate, just want to check if I can set it up and everything works. If so will do ASAP.

Comment: When you include the role model with the organisations model for users.findall, I dont see the role attached to the request. Its basically no different then just including organisations without role. Does sequelize support this on a join on a junction table?

Comment: Yes it does support this ! If you want to check the query being made to debug, you can activate it in the sequelize config. Doing so, every SQL query would be logged so you can verify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177077/discussion-between-eglu-and-philippeauriach).

Answer (score 0):

**It may vary upon your requirements of fetching the data from these  3 tables
Consider this Example :
Tables : login, userProfile, farmer
Requirements : Farmer has one user Profile , User Profile has one Login.
Along with these tables we can register a user as a Farmer.**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
farmer.js

module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Farmer = Sequelize.define("farmer", { /*attributes*/});
  return Farmer;
};

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
login.js

module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Login = Sequelize.define("login", {*attributes*/});

  return Login;
};
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
userProfile.js

module.exports = (Sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserProfile = Sequelize.define("userProfile", {*attributes*/});

  return UserProfile;
};

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
index.js

const dbConfig = require("../config/dbConfig"); // your config file
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

//object initilize. (pass parameter to constructor)
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  operatorsAliases: false, //hide errors
  pool: {
    max: dbConfig.pool.max,
    min: dbConfig.pool.min,
    acquire: dbConfig.pool.acquire,
    idle: dbConfig.pool.idle,
  },
});

sequelize
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB connected!");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error " + err);
  });

const db = {}; // Empty object

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.login = require("./login.js")(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.userProfile = require("./userProfile.js")(sequelize, DataTypes);
db.farmer = require("./farmer.js")(sequelize, DataTypes);

//relations
db.farmer.userProfile = db.farmer.belongsTo(db.userProfile);

db.userProfile.login = db.userProfile.belongsTo(db.login);

db.sequelize
  .sync({ force: false }) //force :true - drop all tables before start
  .then(() => {
    console.log("yes-sync done!");
  });

module.exports = db;

//Declare follwing things in a separate location (may be controllers__.js
-----------INSERT DATA (CREATE)--------------------------

const saved = await Farmer.create(
    {
      supplierCode: "SUP0001",
      userProfile: {
        firstName: "ssss",
        middleName: "ssss",
        lastName: "ssss",
        address: "ssss",
        login: {
          name: "ssss",
          email: "ssss",
          password: "ssss",
          role: "ssss",
          lastLogin: null,
          avatar: "ssss",
          status: "ssss",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      include: [
        {
          association: Farmer.userProfile,
          include: [Login],
        },
      ],
    }
  );
```

Observe the usage of the include option in the Farmer.create call. That is necessary for Sequelize to understand what you are trying to create along with the association.

Note: here, our user model is called farmer, with a lowercase f - This means that the property in the object should also be farmer. If the name given to sequelize.define was Farmer, the key in the object should also be Farmer.

```
-----------FETCH DATA (SELECT)-------------------------- 

const users = await Farmer.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        association: Farmer.userProfile,
        include: [Login],
      },
    ],
  });

Output:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "supplierCode": "SUP0001",
        "createdAt": "2021-11-17T07:39:13.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-11-17T07:39:13.000Z",
        "userProfileId": 1,
        "userProfile": {
            "id": 1,
            "firstName": "ssss",
            "middleName": "ssss",
            "lastName": "ssss",
            "address": "ssss",
            "createdAt": "2021-11-17T07:39:13.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-11-17T07:39:13.000Z",
            "loginId": 1,
            "login": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ssss",
                "email": "ssss",
                "password": "ssss",
                "role": "ssss",
                "lastLogin": null,
                "avatar": "ssss",
                "status": "ssss",
                "createdAt": "2021-11-17T07:39:13.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-11-17T07:39:13.000Z"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Assume you want to add another user Role/Type (we have Farmer already). then you can make coordinater.js (example user role/type) and defind attributes

in above index.js  you can add this relation

//Coordinator relation

```
db.coordinator.userProfile = db.coordinator.belongsTo(db.userProfile, {
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
```

Now you can register users with  different users Roles/Types :
Coordinator.create.... give correct associations